# Scan html div class for message

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making extension for chrome that inspects html web source and scans if any of div class youWrap contains certain word and if yes then it changes text of placeholder in textarea id="Comment".
I have followed some questions from here and youtube and I have manifest.json file, icon.png and popup.html and javascript file being loaded. But now im stuck and im not sure how to make script to keep running and scan.
Im not expecting you to write the full script for me but im not sure where to read about it since im new to javascript and webpages.

On the webpage this is div tag that contains the message:

```
<div class="youWrap">message</div>
```

An this is the text area:

```
<textarea id="Comment" class="form-control" name="Comment" placeholder="Textarea..."></textarea>
```

Manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "ext name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This is extension desc.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "mypopup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
      //match url
    ],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: For clarification, are you scanning the HTML source text itsself, (a very long string) or are you checking the DOM of the page after it was loaded? (DOM nodes) 'html web source' just confused me, sorry.

Comment: you are able to load the content script?

Comment: yes, i have content.js file which has only alert function that is getting popup on specific webpage and thats all. @Shilly, i use inspect function in chrome, im sorry as im new to html

Comment: @ChrisK.PalmaChwialkowski: Share your code (Manifest.json, popup.html, popus.js etc), will help you to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

This will select all the div having youWrap class containing your required text

```
var elements=$(".youWrap:contains('message')");
```

And this will change the placeholder text

```
if(elements.length>0)
{
$("#Comment").attr("placehoder","text");
}
```

Comment: This is what i need, thank you. Do i paste it into content.js file and do i need to add any line to manifest file or popup.html?

Comment: you need to understand what is happening.You need to use it in your content script.You also have to make sure your have jquery added to your manifest in your content script for the code to work.let me know if its working for you...

Comment: I have edited in the manifest file. In content.js there is script you gave me. Can you have a look? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: just include a jquery.js containing jquery script  in your manifest under content script and use the the above code in your content.js

Comment: Im sorry i dont know how to do that im all new to webpage scripting.

Comment: No, I only know java and some html. I will probably pick it up im just not sure how to make it run by now.

Comment: then it would be a bit difficult for you... for now the only you can do open this link in the browser https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js copy the code and save it in the jquery.js file add it to your content script and and in content js paste my code ...

Comment: I did all that but still nothing. I think i will keep digging and read about it because even if i paste $("body").append('Test'); in content.js it does not appear. Thanks so much for your help anyway.

Comment: Providing a jQuery solution to a question that is not tagged with jQuery is often not helpful. If the OP wanted a jQuery based solution, they could have/should have tagged the question with jQuery, or mentioned it in the question. In fact, the [javascript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) explicitly states: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: Bhuwan (and @ChrisK.PalmaChwialkowski) : Suggesting to use jQuery in an extension for something, that is **trivial** to code in vanilla JavaScript, is counterproductive. If you impose the requirement of using jQuery in the extension's content script, that is *potentially* loading jQuery into *every single page*, which could be 100's of tabs at the same time. jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. You did this *only for the **convenience** of saving a few characters* in your own code (Specifically, just using the equivalent of `document.querySelectorAll()` `.forEach()` and `.setAttribute()`).

Answer (score 0):

### References:

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

You can take the following code as a reference for adding some HTML Code.

#### `manifest.json`

This file registers content script to extension.

```
{
"name":"Inject DOM",
"description":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718742",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.co.in/*","https://www.google.co.in/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### `myscript.js`

A trivial script for adding a button to `Google` page

```
// Checking page title
if (document.title.indexOf("Google") != -1) {
    //Creating Elements
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    //Appending to DOM 
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

### `Output`

You see a button added to a desired page

[image]

You can extend this sample script for your desired functionality